# Wild fly 22 Final and Log4j + Not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss, log4j

I added below jar in Lib folder

```
log4j-1.2 api-2.17.0 jar
log4j-api-2.17.0 jar
log4j-core-2.17.0 jar
```

And as suggested in jboss forum, I added below `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` under `WEB-INF` in war project.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
   <deployment>
     <exclusions>  
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
     </exclusions>  
   </deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But still server log is print, no application logs in my console.

My `log4j.properties` in `classpath` has below setting.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, consoleAppender, fileAppender

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L 
%m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - 
%m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=${jboss.server.base.dir}/log/wm/sample.log
```

Can somebody help me in pointing what am I missing in the above set?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So you are excluding log4j2, from jboss, you are including a log4j 1 configuration and wonder why it isn't working?

Comment: @M.deinum We have legacy application there we are using log4j1.x and we have some classes which have been deprecated in lo4j2.x, so that's why As apache suggest we are using log4j -api-2.17.0 compatibility jar along with log4j-api-2.17.0 and log4j-core-2.17.0 jar. Its working fine if we are suing only the log4j-api-1.2.8 jar, while excluding the above org.apache.lo4j, but while replacing log4j-api-1.2.8 to above three jar its not working.

Comment: Your configuration is for log4j 1 **not** log4j2. So you want to use log4j2 but aren't configuring it.